# Cannot get return right in this date and month method - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, switch-statement, android-date, ordinal

I have been fiddling around with this method that I created and cannot manage to get it to work.
I either get string cannot be converted to int or require a return, but then I cannot enter the `monthString` variable in the return statement as it is out of scope of the ordinal method and cannot find the variable.

```
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Calendar;

/**
 * Created by avi31 on 31/01/2018.
 */


import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class ProfileSettings extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "Profile_Settings";


    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener;
    private TextView mDisplayDate;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
        mDisplayDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDate);

        mDisplayDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(
                        ProfileSettings.this,
                        android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Panel,
                        mDateSetListener,
                        year, month, day);
                dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
                dialog.show();
            }
        });


        mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int day) {
                month = month + 1;
                Log.w(TAG, "Date of Birth: " + day + "/" + month + "/" + year);

                String date = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
                mDisplayDate.setText(date);
                Toast.makeText(ProfileSettings.this, date, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                ordinal(day, month, year);
            }


            String ordinal(int day, int month, int year) {
                String[] day1 = new String[]{"th", "st", "nd", "rd", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th"};

                String monthString = "Default";

                switch (day % 100) {
                    case 11:
                    case 12:
                    case 13:

                        switch (month) {
                            case 1:  monthString = "January";
                                break;
                            case 2:  monthString = "February";
                                break;
                            case 3:  monthString = "March";
                                break;
                            case 4:  monthString = "April";
                                break;
                            case 5:  monthString = "May";
                                break;
                            case 6:  monthString = "June";
                                break;
                            case 7:  monthString = "July";
                                break;
                            case 8:  monthString = "August";
                                break;
                            case 9:  monthString = "September";
                                break;
                            case 10: monthString = "October";
                                break;
                            case 11: monthString = "November";
                                break;
                            case 12: monthString = "December";
                                break;



                        }



                }
                Log.w(TAG, day + "" + day1[day % 10] + " " + monthString + " " + year);
                return day + monthString + year;
            }


            public void buttonClicked(View view) {
                if (view.getId() == R.id.btn_exit) {
                    finish();
                    Log.w(TAG, "Exit back to previous activity");
                }
            }
        };


    }
```

Comment: `ordinal(day, month, year);` you are not using the return value of your function

Comment: Thanks for your comment - i tried returning that in my method but then get unreachable statement on  'Log.w(TAG, day + "" + day1[day % 10] + " " + monthString + " " + year);'

Comment: so you mean your code is not even compiling ?

Comment: Not at the moment :( I have added full class to question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String ordinal(int day, int month, int year) {
        String[] day1 = new String[]{"th", "st", "nd", "rd", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th"};

        String monthString = ""; //declare here

        switch (day % 100) {
            case 11:
            case 12:
            case 13:
                Log.w(TAG, day + "th");

                switch (month) {
                    case 1:  monthString = "January";
                        break;
                    case 2:  monthString = "February";
                        break;
                    case 3:  monthString = "March";
                        break;
                    case 4:  monthString = "April";
                        break;
                    case 5:  monthString = "May";
                        break;
                    case 6:  monthString = "June";
                        break;
                    case 7:  monthString = "July";
                        break;
                    case 8:  monthString = "August";
                        break;
                    case 9:  monthString = "September";
                        break;
                    case 10: monthString = "October";
                        break;
                    case 11: monthString = "November";
                        break;
                    case 12: monthString = "December";
                        break;
                }
                break; //you're missing this break after the case
        }
        return day + monthString;
    }
```

Comment: Hi thank you very much and this helped me a lot, however I initialised monthString to "default" instead of January, February etc. and it keeps giving me that in the log.. I have updated code above

Comment: You are not even calling the function  'ordinal(day, month, year)' instead 'String origin = ordinal(day, month, year)'

Comment: +1 Thanks for that - i have added that, but monthString is still giving me the value i declared where you commented

Comment: I think your problem is that after your inside switch cases (after month is set), you are not adding break for the outer case. do you understand me?

Comment: Thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring the variable month string inside the case13, just before the second switch statement, move and initialize the monthString variable outside the first switch statement.

Comment: Hi I changed that but still getting ertror

Comment: When I compile in android studio I get monthString might not have been initialised in the return statement

Comment: The error probably can be, the variable, monthString is not initialized, initialize the variable, String monthVariable = null; this will fix the error

Answer (score 0):

`String monthString;` is defined within the switch statement, and hence, has limited scope. Just move it outside.

Move it right after the line you define `day1` array.

Comment: Hi puneet thanks for your comment, I have done that now but still getting error. I have added full class code question

Comment: Sorry variable monthString might not have been initialised in the return statement

Comment: String monthString = ""; You were trying to use a variable before initializing it. The statement `day % 100` can have 28 other values besides 11,12 and 13. For these values, `monthString` remains uninitialized. Initializing it to a blank value or adding a default handler will eliminate the error. (Re edited for spelling mistakes/formatting.)

Comment: Hello puneet, i have added "default" in for monthString - but I keep having "default" returned as the value for this variable

Comment: Please refer to my comment about the fact that your `day % 100` can have 28 other values besides the one you are handling. Therefore, If you select anything besides 11, 12 and 13 you will get the default value back.